# How to disable Python shell spawning "less" with "help"

Tags: python, shell

Title says it all.  I'd prefer that Python's shell use `cat` instead of `less` when displaying help so that the contents of help is inline with the rest of the shell session.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [`help()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#help) function seems to respect the [`PAGER` environment variable](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Guide_to_Unix/Environment_Variables#PAGER). So the following works for me to switch to `cat` as the pager instead of `less`:

```
PAGER=cat python
```

```
>>> import os
>>> help(os)
```

You can also change the environment variable from inside Python:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['PAGER'] = 'cat'
>>>
>>> help(os)
```

But note that this will only have an effect if you do this *before the first time* you use the pager, because the pager is [cached in `pydoc.py`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/85de13b746ac/Lib/pydoc.py#l1405) after the first time it has been determined.

Answer (score 16):

This also seems to work:

```
>>> import pydoc
>>> pydoc.pager = pydoc.plainpager
```

This works even if you have already invoked the help command, as it replaces the cached version in pydoc.py.

Comment: nice. its working

Comment: FWIW, if you've already run `help()`, you don't need to import `pydoc`: `sys.modules['pydoc'].pager = sys.modules['pydoc'].plainpager`